# Linux read whitespaces and special characters

Tags: linux, bash

I want to read with whitespaces and special characters because I need to delete file with the name of that string. I don't know how to deal with "\" and last spaces in read; I am probably doing it wrong.

```
     while read LINE
  do
    for arg in $LINE
    do  
    if [ "${args}" = "" ]
    then
        args="${args}"
    else
        args="${args}' '"
    fi     
    args="${args}${arg}"
    done
```

I need to do something like that `echo sadsad asddsa ;' dsasa  | ./sth.sh | xargs -l rm -f`

I think that I need to set IFS to "|" but it doesn't work properly. I need to read input end call it.

EDIT: Ok, I think I only need to do something with xargs and sed.

Ok, almost thant I have some errors but I get file name

```
find  *.txt -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

This works fine for me :). Problem probably solved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing find to echo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116184/changing-find-to-echo)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
while read -r line
do
  echo rm -- "$line"
done
```

`-r` means that backslash don't get special treatment.

Comment: echo sadsad asddsa dssd \ dsasa| ./zad3.sh | xargs -l rm -f
i get this rm -- sadsad asddsa dssd  dsasa