# Changing find to echo

Tags: bash

This is almost good

```
find  *.txt -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

And i want to have something like that

```
echo *.txt ./zad3.sh | xargs -l rm -f
```

First version is good because I can delete file with white spaces but I can't use my script to select file to delete.

Second version I can select files but I can't delete file with white spaces.

I want to find files with end on .txt and delete some of them. zad3.sh is a script wich is returning file name if i agree to delete it rm catch the name and delete it. It works only for file without white space and special characters. Second version is better but i cant put my script inside it.

```
find  *.txt -print0| xargs -0 ./zad3.sh |xargs  rm -f
```

it works almost but i cant pass arg to rm and part of my code

```
pick()
{
  while read LINE
  do
    for arg in $LINE
    do   
      echo "${arg}[tn]"  >&2
      read x <&2
      if [ "${x}" = "t" ]; then
    echo $arg
      fi
    done
  done
}

  for arg in "$@"
  do 
      echo "${arg}[tn]" >&2
      read x <&2
      if [ "${x}" = "t" ]; then
    echo $arg
      fi
  done
if [ $# = 0 ]; then
  pick
fi
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want to do here.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the users same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115578/linux-read-whitespaces-and-special-characters

Answer (score 1):

What I would probably do is change the `zad.sh` script to only take a single argunment and to not output anything. Instead return success (`exit 0`) if the file can be deleted, and failure (`exit 1`) if it cannot. e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash -u
FILE="$1"
if can_delete $FILE
then
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Now you can easily use your shell script as a filter in the find command

```
find  *.txt -exec ./zad3.sh {} \; -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

So any file which `zad3.sh` fails for will not make the `print0` and so will not be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky, but:

```
find -name "*.txt" -exec rm -i $( ./zad3.sh {} ) 2> /dev/null \;
```

This will `rm` only the files echo'd from your script, and the other files that don't get echo'd will pass nothing to `rm`, but the stderr from trying to `rm` without a file name is redirected to /dev/null.

Also, you want to quote the *.txt or else globbing will expand the * before it gets to the find command.

Comment: I dont want use find cuz i cant run my script. I need to use xargs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the suspicion you want to do something like this:

```
select fname in *.txt;
do
    echo about to delete "$fname"
    rm -v "$fname"
done
```

Exit the loop with break;

A simple demo of a script that will keep posting a new list of files to be deleted:

```
PS3="select file or '0' to stop? "
while ls *.txt; do 
    select file in *.txt; do 
         if [ -z "$file" ]; then break 2; fi

         rm -v "$file"; 
         break; # we want a new list
    done; 
done
```

Comment: then tell us that. you're being very vague and shouting us down? I cannot _smell_ that you know this. `I need to use my own about` (?!) `how to do that` (what?!) `without it` (without what?). Nah, never mind.